# Are these baobab or acacia trees?

Tags: identification, trees

I have some questions about some trees present in my study areas. I think there must be acacias trees and baobabs, but it's hard for me to distinguish them.

Maybe there are also some additional trees someone can help me with.

The ones in the front, at the right side in picture 2 must be eucalyptus trees.

The pictures are taken in the north of Ethiopia!

*Click on photo for full size*
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added your photos with links to the full size versions.  You should be able to do it yourself in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first picture the closest two (that are fully in view) appear to be Baobab based on their thick trunk and the fact that they are leafless. Baobab are excellent survivers, hence why they ditch their leaves so early ( to conserve water and protect themselves from infection). Also in the first picture there are two trees in line with each other in the upper right. The first appears to be a flat top acacia, of all the trees the only one I will confidently say is, but they come in so many variations. In the second picture the only distinguishable tree is a Baobab sitting just slightly to the left and slightly above the center of the picture behind a smaller tree, the thinner trees without leaves scattered about the front could also be Baobab but I would not say for sure.

Do you have any closer pictures of the plush tree sitting all the way to the left in the middle of the picture set behind the smaller trees? I only ask because it sticks out and one of the most interesting parts of Ethiopia's plant life is the diversity of how some trees store nutrients to protect themselves while others yield so much value that have warranted cultivation

Comment: I just dropped 4 additional pictures. I remember the trees on picture 3 and 4 were very thorny, they must be acacias? 
Pitures 5 and 6 are what the local people told me to be dat tree or oat tree in English (daro in Tigrinya language). Though I have my doubts. I just started thinking they also might be baobabs?

Comment: What surprises me is that indeed, a lot of trees do not have leave, though the pictures were taken in the middle of the rainy season. They have to have leaves at some time of the year, no?

Comment: Whoa! that tree is out of this world. that is an awesome picture! Yes i believe the Baobabs should have leaves in July and August. The Baobabs store so much water that they can be tapped, if the trees were being tapped for their water it would most likely affect their annual cycles!

Comment: That could be a Baobabs or the leaves look more like a warka, but it is just so huge.